# Spatial resolution for Bioclim datasets

Tags: resolution, modelling, resampling, climate

I am new in using [Bioclim](http://www.worldclim.org/bioclim) datasets. I want to model future spread of *Prosopis juliflora* using landsat 30m. I want to add other datasets like temperature, ppt, elevation, soil moisture, pH, etc. Any idea what is the resolution of the Bioclim data is or whether it can be resampled to 30m?

Answer (score 3):

The finest resolution of Bioclim is 30 arc-seconds, which translates to approximately 1 kilometer (1000m).

You can certainly resample the data to 30 meters but this would be quite invalid because the assumption in a model is that you are representing a functional resolution with the data. Since you are not adding any additional information to the climate surfaces, your functional scale would still be 1km.

You could also unintentionally add a autocovariance structure to the data, that is purely a function of the interpolation algorithm and could be directly be interpreted as error/bias.